# What is the bash meaning of [134-6] expression

Tags: bash, expression

I came across this expression and I'm not sure about its meaning.

It is:

```
ls ab?*.c[134-6]
```

I understand "?" and "*", but what about [134-6]? I know that [1-6] means "every number from 1 to 6, but what does this expression mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Means exactly what you think it does you just need to parse it correctly.

```
$ touch a{1..6}
$ ls
a1  a2  a3  a4  a5  a6
$ ls a[134-6]
a1  a3  a4  a5  a6

$ touch ab{c{,c},d{,d}}.c{1,2,3,4,5,6}
$ ls
abc.c1  abc.c4  abcc.c1  abcc.c4  abd.c1  abd.c4  abdd.c1  abdd.c4
abc.c2  abc.c5  abcc.c2  abcc.c5  abd.c2  abd.c5  abdd.c2  abdd.c5
abc.c3  abc.c6  abcc.c3  abcc.c6  abd.c3  abd.c6  abdd.c3  abdd.c6
$ ls ab?*.c[134-6]
abc.c1  abc.c5   abcc.c3  abcc.c6  abd.c4  abdd.c1  abdd.c5
abc.c3  abc.c6   abcc.c4  abd.c1   abd.c5  abdd.c3  abdd.c6
abc.c4  abcc.c1  abcc.c5  abd.c3   abd.c6  abdd.c4
```

Comment: so in fact you could say `[13-6]`

Comment: That didn't do so in my tests, but maybe there was something else wrong, thank you for clarifying!